# Tab bar buttons all gray

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5

I'm trying to create a tab bar controller but last time I did it was with iOS 6.1. But now when I put a Tab bar Controller on the storyboard it doesn't show the buttons, and any modifications I try to make on background and text does not appear. Anyone knows how can I fix it?

Below is an image of the described problem.

[image: a newly created tab bar controller not showing the buttons]

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to select the tab bar (not the controller) to change the background color.

Comment: try adding images to your tab bar items. Then your tabbar should not be grayed out. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I did it some months ago and it worked. The problem is that on the time I made the first flow I did not have the images. Then I had to work with the grayed bar until I discovered it could get fixed by just adding any image... Thanks anyway! Want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is just mentioned in the comments and I struggled with this problem for quite a while, this is a solution:

**Add an image** to the `Tab Bar Item` and you will see the normal view of the tab bar on the specific `View Controller` where you changed it. When **every single** `Tab Bar Item` got an image you will also see the normal appearance in your `Tab Bar Controller`.

This is the only fix that worked for me after reinstalling Xcode and rebooting my mac which both didn't solve the problem.

I'd appreciate other solutions as I think this hasn't always been this way.

Comment: It is incredible how it seems to be a bug that its already notified and there's no solution yet for it. It used to show dummy icons before Xcode 5 I think... Anyway, thanks for putting it as an Answer! :)