# bar button item color is not same at Xcode and IOS device

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm having trouble with setting menu bar item color. I prepared menu image at three different sizes and created media.xcassets. They're all png with white color for lines and have transparent backgrounds.
The problem is, bar button item color is not same at Xcode and IOS device, it's gray at ios device and white at development environment as expected.
Inside xcode and at simulator it looks like.

[image: xcode simulator]

When it deploy to development device, it looks like below.
[image: ios device]

All button item attributes inspector below.

[image: attributes inspector]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the button background image, not the button image.

```
button1.setBackgroundImage(image1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

if you use storyboard

[image]

Comment: Can I set it at storyboard?

Comment: It's not image, but bar item.

Comment: ok, try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642476/tab-bar-buttons-all-gray